# What were the other nine questions in the Chuunin exams?

Tags: naruto

I'm not exactly expecting to find a full list or anything, but I was wondering if the manga/anime gave any clues to what the questions might have been. Checking the manga, I found that the first question was a [cryptogram](http://i13.mangareader.net/naruto/41/naruto-1565602.jpg) and that the second question was about [tactics](http://i37.mangareader.net/naruto/41/naruto-1565605.jpg).

However, I could not find any more information about the questions from the manga. Does the anime provide any more insight into what the first 9 questions might have been?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. is cryptography
2. is figuring out trajectory of a thrown shuriken, as well as predicting the furthest possible range of a shuriken and describing how that conclusion was reached
3. appears to have a topographical map involving a mountain

As far as I can tell, no other question is explicitly discussed or clearly shown, but none of the rest of them have diagrams or maps, so presumably they are all math or logic questions.

One that Sakura is looking at is shown but (at least at the resolution I'm looking at it on) the kanji just shows up as black blobs, and I'm not sure what it says.

According to Sakura (in the English dub), they are "problems based on uncertainty and requiring complex mechanical energy analysis." They are also stated to get more difficult as they go.